# How to run TestSuit from command line?

Tags: android, testing, appium, test-suite

I'm using Appium, and I have three classes with Appium tests. I have .xml file which declares a TestSuit and I can run the TestSuit from eclipse without any problem.

My question is, how can I run the same TestSuit for Appium tests from the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you run them in eclipse?

Comment: Using the play button on the TestSuit.xml and it runs with JUnit configurations. you can see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899940/how-to-create-appium-testsuite-in-android-studio/28903037#28903037    @Blundell

Comment: If you edit the junit configuration you can see what commands eclipse is running

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JUnit.jar is in your classpath. Then use this command from console:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore (test class name)
```